# ng-options setting "selected" value

Tags: angularjs

I am fairly new to Angular. I am using ng-options it works great it, saves the value to database. The issue I running into is when I bring back the saved value from database it does not select the correct value in the drop down. I ran into this issue before and after searching for hours

```
<select ng-options="pt.Value as pt.DisplayText for pt in test_results" ng-model="sel_phase.DVPPTestStatus" ng-disabled="!sel_phase" class="form-control"></select>
```

is the code. When I select the value say "1" it saves it to database. When it loads sel_phase.DVPPTestStatus has value of 1 but never sets the dropdown. to the correct value.

Can please someone help?

Comment: post `test_results` array

Comment: What is the value of `pt.Value`? What is the value of `sel_phase.DVPPTestStatus`? They need to be `===`. Note that `1` is not `===` to `'1'`, for example.

Comment: @JB Nizet Thank you very much I had to change to int and that did the trick. I feel so stupid for spending hours on this issue. Thank you